# What happens if an attacker steals my sim card number?

Tags: simcard

The Sprint chat guy asked for my sim card number (ICCID) and I'm a little concerned about how sensitive it is. One possibility I can think of is being able to intercept SMS 2-factor Auth.

Comment: That's why SMS 2FA is not considered a secure way to implement 2FA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The really secret stuff is stored inside of the SIM card in the form of an authentication key. The ICCID is not really very secret at all, it just uniquely identifies the SIM card but provides no way to perform the authentication process without the authentication key.